# Can I make a table cell have a different color if the value ==sucess with angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

HI Im new to angular js im trying to display the json content as table.is it possible to change the color based on the value in the json content?

i've tried by adding ng-class which was not working.

Please find the code i've tried

```js
    
angular.module('mApp')
        .controller('mController', main);

    function main($http) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.name = "sathya";

        var jsonData = '{"header":{"columns":[{"name":"Services","subcolumns":[{"name":""}]},{"name":"Server1","subcolumns":[{"name":"Status"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"name":"Server2","subcolumns":[{"name":"Status"},{"name":"Action"}]},{"name":"Server3","subcolumns":[{"name":"Status"},{"name":"Action"}]}]},"rows":{"data":[[{"value": "Service1"}, {"value": "Running"}, {"value": "action"}, {"value": "Stopped"}, {"value": "Action"}, {"value": "Running"}, {"value": "Action"}],[{"value":"Service2"},{"value":"Running"},{"value": "Action"},{"value": "Stopped"},{"value":"Action"},{"value":"Running"},{"value": "Action"}]]}}';
        vm.table = JSON.parse(jsonData);
        vm.subHeaders = function () {
            var subs = [];
            vm.table.header.columns.forEach(function (col) {
                col.subcolumns.forEach(function (sub) {
                    subs.push(sub);
                });
            });
            return subs;
        };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />    
</head>
<body ng-controller="mController as mn">
    <div class="main">      
        <div class="bodycontent">
            <div class="mainnav">                
                <div>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="{{col.subcolumns.length}}" ng-repeat="col in mn.table.header.columns">{{col.name}}</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th ng-repeat="col in mn.subHeaders()">{{col.name}}</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="row in mn.table.rows.data">
                            <td ng-repeat="cell in row" ng-class="{'status_green' : cell.value=='Running', 'status_red' : cell.value=='Stopped'}">{{cell.value}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!---->
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="App/app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="App/Main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obviously you can. Please create a [mcve] and show us your code - There's more than one way to do it

Answer (score 0):

you could use `ng-if` statement and try with this:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in jsonData" style="width:25%">
 <table class="table table-bordered" ng-repeat="a in i.data">
         <tr>
           <th>Value</th>
         </tr>
         <tr ng-repeat="v in a">
          <td ng-if="v.value !== 'Success'"> {{v.value}}</td>
          <td ng-if="v.value === 'Success'" style="color:green"> {{v.value}}</td>    
         </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

plunker: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/99ySQe5flCzaDbax?preview

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

here what i did, and it's simple

```
<td><h6 ng-show="employee.status=='Active'" class="green">{{employee.status}}</h6><h6 ng-show="employee.status=='Deactive'" class="yellow">{{employee.status}}</h6> </td>
```